# Get list people you are following on twitter

Tags: twitter

IS it possible to something like this:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/xxxxxx.json
```

but instead of list of people following you, list of people you are following?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like this is what you need:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?id=:screen_name_or_user_id
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids

Once you have the list of ID's returned, you can look them up by passing them as a comma delimited list to another API call:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=[comma delimited list goes here]
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup

Comment: How do I then get the names of those?

Comment: You can do that in one call. See my answer for that.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/friends.json?screen_name=bitboxer
```

that way you don't have to do two calls for id and than for details.

Comment: Doesn't return all friends, I only get 20 records returned.

Comment: FYI: to match all, you need to page through the results: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list

Answer (score 3):

The new 1.1 URL you need to call is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json

Full documentation is at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('tmhOAuth.php');
require_once('tmhUtilities.php');
$profile_username = "abcdefg"; //twitter username
$oauth_access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //Your access token
$oauth_access_token_secret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"; //Your access token secret
$consumer_key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"; //Your key
$consumer_secret = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"; //Your secret key
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
    'user_token' => $oauth_access_token,
    'user_secret' => $oauth_access_token_secret,
    'curl_ssl_verifypeer' => false
));
$code = $tmhOAuth->request(
    'GET', 
    $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/friends/ids'), 
    array(
        'screen_name' => $profile_username,
        'count' => '10'
    )
);
$response = $tmhOAuth->response['response'];
$following_ids = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($following_ids);
```